# searchBar in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, searchbar, jsondecoder

program code
how to add a search for the data of tableview

```
struct jsonstruct:Decodable {
 var name:String
 var Id : Int = 0
 let MobileNumber:String
 let gender:String


enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name = "name"
    case Id = "Id"
    case gender = "gender"


}
}

class ProfileVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource , UISearchBarDelegate{

var isSearch : Bool = false
var arrFilter:[String] = []
@IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!
var arrayData = [AnyObject]()
var arrdata = [jsonstruct]()
var ListArray : [[String : AnyObject]] = [[String : AnyObject]]()
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
let url = "......"
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  postmethod()
    tblView.reloadData()


  func postmethod(){

    let params: [String : String] = ["Id" : "01"]


    Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

            for (key, value) in params
            {
                multipartFormData.append((value.data(using: .utf8))!, 
       withName: key)
            }
      },
        to: url,
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                print(response.value as Any)

                if let result = response.result.value {

                    if let jsonstruct = result as? NSDictionary {

                        let ListArray = jsonstruct.value(forKey: "List") 
                         as! NSArray
                        let name = ListArray.value(forKey: "name") as! 
                         NSArray
                        let Id = ListArray.value(forKey: "Id") as! NSArray
                       .......
                       .......

                       if let dict = response.result.value as? [String : 
                   AnyObject], let list = dict["List"] as? [[String : 
                 AnyObject]] {
                            self.arrayData = list as [AnyObject]

                            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                                self.tblView.reloadData() 
                            }
                        }

                        for mainarr in self.arrdata{

             print(mainarr.name,":",mainarr.Id,":",mainarr.gender,":".....)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.tblView.reloadData()
                            }

                        }
                    } 
                }
   }

        case .failure(_): break
            }
    }
    )
   }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath 
  indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

   }
  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
  {
    return 1
  }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: 
   Int) -> Int {
        if(isSearch) {
            return self.arrFilter.count
        }
        return self.arrayData.count;
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
   IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
  {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: 
   indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    var jsonDict =  self.arrayData[indexPath.row] as? [String:AnyObject]
    cell.lblname.text = jsonDict?["name"] as? String
    cell.lblGender.text = jsonDict?["gender"] as? String
    cell.lblId.text = jsonDict?["Id"] as? String


    return cell
   }


    func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath: 
   NSIndexPath) {
    if(isSearch){
        cell.textLabel?.text = arrFilter[forRowAtIndexPath.row]
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = arrayData[forRowAtIndexPath.row] as! String;
    }
   }


  //MARK: UISearchbar delegate
   func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    isSearch = true;
  }

  func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    isSearch = false;
  }

   func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    isSearch = false;
  }

  func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    isSearch = false;
  }

        self.tblView.reloadData()
    }
  }
```

The data from api is stored and viewed it in tableview. But the data in tableview i want to filter using a search with the name and id ....
How it Possible???

searchBar
A UISearchBar object provides the user interface for a search field on a bar, but it’s the application’s responsibility to implement the actions when buttons are tapped. At a minimum, the delegate needs to perform the actual search when text is entered in the text field

Comment: I have a full example of searching/filtering a UITableView using a UISearchController here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490103/select-filtered-search-results/50490408#50490408

Comment: this answer might be help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41663233/tableview-search-in-swift

Comment: But how can i change  var arrdata = [jsonstruct]()

Comment: var arrdata = [jsonstruct]()    between var names=["John",
        "Terry",
        "Martin",
        "Steven",
        "Michael",
        "Thomas",
        "Jason",
        "Matthew"]